# if statement with pandas as_matrix function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = [['a','b'], ['c', 'd']]

if not (['a', 'b'] in df.as_matrix(['col'])):
    print("hello")
```

Since `['a', 'b']` is in `df.as_matrix(['col'])`, `print(hello)` should not be executed.  However, it is.

I do not understand why this is the case.  How would I edit my code so that my if statement does not print "hello"?

Comment: @JohnGalt That worked! I'm happy to choose your answer as the correct answer if you would like to post it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.tolist()` instead

```
In [569]: ['a', 'b'] in df['col'].tolist()
Out[569]: True
```

Or, iterate the Numpy array.

```
In [570]: any([x[0] == ['a', 'b'] for x in df.as_matrix(['col'])])
Out[570]: True
```

---

Details

```
In [571]: df.as_matrix(['col'])
Out[571]:
array([[['a', 'b']],
       [['c', 'd']]], dtype=object)

In [572]: df['col'].tolist()
Out[572]: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```